# How to extend str.isspace()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, whitespace

[`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) is very convenient to check whether a line is empty (it encompasses the space and return characters).

Is it possible to extend with some other characters (say, a comma) which should also be treated as "space characters" during the check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `str.strip()` with the characters you consider as unimportant, and check if the result is empty:

```
a="  ,  "

if not a.strip(", \n\t\v\r"):
    print("empty")
```

(`str.strip` removes all char occurrences of the passed parameter from both ends of the string, in that case `str.lstrip` or `str.rstrip` would work the same way, and would even be slightly faster)

What slightly bothers me is that it creates a throwaway string just to test that it's empty. I liked abamert `set` concept, although creating a `set` just to use `issubset` is done the wrong way (it creates a throwaway `set`, so same issue). I would do:

```
spaceset = set(", \n\r\v")   # initialized once and for all
```

then use `issuperset` on the existing set, with the string as argument:

```
spaceset.issuperset(a)
```

(that doesn't create a `set` everytime)

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to extend `str.isspace`. But you can do the same thing yourself, slightly more verbosely, in a few ways.

An explicit loop:

```
all(c in my_space_set for c in s)
```

Make a set:

```
set(s).issubset(my_space_set)
```

Or a regular expression with a character class, or…

Comment: Yes, I actually use `set(line.decode()) <= set(', \n')` and wondered whether the extending would work, out of curiosity (I discover new things in Python everyday). Thanks for the answer! (waiting for the cooldown to accept)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regular expressions

```
import re

def is_all_modified_whitespace(s)
    return not re.search(r'[^\s,]', s)

is_all_modified_whitespace(s)
```

Regular expressions are great for stuff like this because they allow you to easily modify the character set to check for.